# NSOutlineview, Expand nested Item with the same name of another item

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm using a custom Plist Editor, I need to use auto save expanded item feature, I can't figure out how to expand a node if an item has other nested item with the same name.

[image: The nested item of Item2 is not able to expand]

This is my "working" code:

```
-(id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView itemForPersistentObject:(id)object {
    LNPropertyListNode *node = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:object];
    return [self itemForNode:node inNodes:[self.rootPropertyListNode children]];
}

-(id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView persistentObjectForItem:(id)item {
    return (LNPropertyListNode*)[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item];
}

-(id)itemForNode:(LNPropertyListNode*)object inNodes:(NSArray*)nodes {
    for (LNPropertyListNode *node in nodes) {
        if ([node.key isEqualToString: object.key]) {
            return node;
        }

        LNPropertyListNode *item = [self itemForNode:object inNodes:node.children];
        if ([item.key isEqualToString:object.key] ) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Are the items and persistent objects unique?

Comment: No, they change every time they are reloaded.

Comment: Are there duplicate persistent objects?

Comment: itemForPersistentObject return:<LNPropertyListNode 0x600002025680 key: “Item2”> <LNPropertyListNode 0x600002025680 key: “Object”> <LNPropertyListNode 0x600002025680 key: “Item1” type: “Dictionary” children: “1 items”> <LNPropertyListNode 0x600002025680 key: “Object” type: “Dictionary” children: “3 items”> persistentObjectForItem return:<LNPropertyListNode 0x6000018f0fc0 key: “Item1”
<LNPropertyListNode 0x6000018f0900 key: “Item2”
<LNPropertyListNode 0x6000018f0cc0 key: “Object”
<LNPropertyListNode 0x6000018f0540 key: “Object”

Comment: I'll take that as "I don't know". `persistentObjectForItem` should translate items to persistent objects and `persistentObjectForItem` should find items matching these persistent objects. The trick is to generate unique persistent objects so you can find the matching items.

Comment: I don't know why the persistentObjectForItem should find parent node but it returns nil value.

Comment: I'm sorry, copied the wrong method. `itemForPersistentObject` should find items matching the persistent objects.